Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(1+\frac{x}{n^2}) g(x) dx$
I want to evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(1+\frac{x}{n^2}) g(x) dx$, where $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is (Lebesgue)-integrable, and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, measurable and continuous at 1.
Approach 1 (confident about this)
My first approach is to use DCT, as follows.

First, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(1+\frac{x}{n^2}) 1_{(-n,n)} \rightarrow f(1)$. Thus, the limit is ideally $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(1) g(x) dx$.
Since $f$ is bounded, $|f(1+\frac{x}{n^2}) g(x)|$ < $M|g(x)|$, where the RHS is integrable, so that by DCT, the above limit is $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(1) g(x) dx$.

Approach 2 (not so confident about this)
My second approach was to note the $n^2$ denominator term and try out more "basic" analysis, since the above approach also seems to work with $n$ in the denominator term? However, I am doubtful about some steps, which I've typed in boldface. Please let me know if those steps are correct or not

For $x \in [-n,n]$, we have that $\frac{x}{n^2} \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $x$. Since $f$ is continuous at $1$, this yields that $f(1+ \frac{x}{n^2}) \rightarrow f(1)$ uniformly on $[-n,n]$. Does this imply that $f(1+ \frac{x}{n^2}) 1_{(-n,n)}(x) \rightarrow f(1)$ uniformly in $x$, too? (I don't think it does, since $x \notin (-n,n) \implies f(1+ \frac{x}{n^2}) 1_{(-n,n)}(x) = 0$) And if it doesn't, then what that means is that "uniformly on $[-n,n]$" is not the same as simply attaching an indicator on that interval...

Supposing, however, that it is the same as attaching an indicator: Since we have a uniform limit now, it'd be nice to express the integral as a limit and then commute things. Hence, since g is integrable, so that $\int g = \int g_n$ for simple functions $g_n$, we have that (working backwards):
$$ \int f(1) g = \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1 + x/n^2) 1_{(-n,n)} g(x) dx = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1 + x/n^2) 1_{(-n,n)} g_m(x) dx $$
$$ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \int f(1 + x/n^2) 1_{(-n,n)} g_m(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f(1 + x/n^2) 1_{(-n,n)} g(x) dx  $$
, where we can commute the limits since (i) the limit with respect to $n$ is uniformly convergent, and (ii) the integral following the second equality sign is really a finite sum.

Your first approach is OK. Your second approach does not work. To see that, just consider $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the constant function $1$. Then, $f$ is a bounded measurable function and continuous at $1$. On the other hand, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$f(1+ \frac{x}{n^2}) 1_{(-n,n)}(x) = 1_{(-n,n)}(x)$$ and $1_{(-n,n)}$ does not converge uniformly to $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.


Your first solution is obviously correct and perhaps the natural one for you integrand $h_n(x)=f(1+xn^{-2})\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}(x)g(x)$ is dominated by either

the integrable function $\|f\|_\infty |g(x)|$,
or the sequence $G_n(x)=\|f\|_\infty|g(x)|\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}$, which satisfies $\lim_n\int G_n=\int \lim G_n$ (by virtue of the monotone convergence theorem here).


Interchanging the order of limit and integral when uniform convergence is present works in the following general situation:


Proposition 1. Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a finite measure space and that $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of functions in $L_1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ that converges uniformly  to a measurable function $f$. Then $f\in L_1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, $\lim_n\int_X|f_n-f|\,d\mu=0$ and $\lim_n\int_Xf_n\,d\mu=\int_X f\,d\mu$.


That $f\in L_1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ follows from uniform convergence and finiteness of $\mu$: There is  $N$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty<1$ for $n\geq N$. Then
$$\int_X|f|\,d\mu\leq \int(|f-f_N|+|f_N|\,d\mu<\mu(X)+\int_X|f_N|\,d\mu<\infty$$
That  $\lim_n\int_X|f_n-f|\,d\mu=0$ follows from uniform convergence. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N_\varepsilon$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty<\epsilon/(\mu(X)+1)$ whenever $n\geq N_\varepsilon$. Thus, for $n\geq N_\varepsilon$
$$\int_X|f_n-f|\,d\mu<\varepsilon$$

Remark: In your example, this criteria laid out abobe does not apply since the sequence $f_n(x)=f(x+xn^{-2})\operatorname{sign}(g(x))\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}(x)$ does not necessarily converge uniformly to $f(1)\operatorname{sign}(g(x))$.

In your example, you have local uniform convergence. In this situation, we can prove the following result which addresses your question about commuting double limits.


Proposition 2.  Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a  finite measure space.  Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of  measurable functions which converges pointwise to $f$ and such that $\sup_n\|f_n\|_\infty=M>\infty$. Assume that there is a sequence of measurable sets $X_m\nearrow X$ such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on each $X_m$. Then $\lim_n\int_{X_n}f_n\,d\mu=\int_X f\,\mu$.

Here is an outline of a proof for Prop. 2: Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that  $\mu(X\setminus X_n)<\varepsilon/(2(M+1))$ for all $n\geq N$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big|\int_Xf-\int_{X_n}f_n\Big|&\leq \int_{X_n}|f-f_n|\,d\mu+\int_{X\setminus X_n}|f|\,d\mu\leq \int_{X_n}|f-f_n|\,d\mu +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&\leq \int_X|f-f_n|\,d\mu +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\end{aligned}$$
Now, by Prop. 1,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_X|f-f_n|\,d\mu&\leq \int_{X_N}|f-f_n|\,d\mu+\int_{X\setminus X_N}|f_n-f|\,d\mu\\
&\leq   \int_{X_N}|f-f_n|\,d\mu + \varepsilon\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$
The desired results follows. It should be noted that this result can be proved by direct application of dominated convergence.
Remark: In your example, let $\mu(dx)=|g(x)|\,dx$, $X_n=[-n,n]$ and $f_n(x)=f(x+xn^{-2})\operatorname{sign}(g(x))$.

The DCT method is fine. The 'classical' analysis (and I do think it is a good exercise to think about these things from time to time) is not fine. A significant first problem is that "$x/n^2\to0$ uniformly on $[-n,n]$" doesn't make sense! Your domain is changing!
Two possibilities where the domain is fixed: $(1)$ talk about uniform convergence on some fixed interval $[-a,a]$, $a$ a constant $(2)$ talk about uniform convergence of $f(1+x/n^2)1_{(-n,n)}(x)$ on the whole real line. But you're correct about $(2)$ - $(2)$ is false.

"uniformly on $[-n,n]$" is not the same as simply attaching an indicator on that interval"

I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, but uniformly on $[-n,n]$ doesn't make sense anyway. The main challenge with many integral problems is that we easily have sufficiently good convergence on fixed compact intervals but weird stuff is happening at infinity; applying a fixed indicator function would help with that, but a variable one indicating a variable domain will give you the same grief.
In your later work, you do several things which are dubious in the classical framework (but of course, easy with the dominated convergence theorem). Immediately, $\lim_{m\to\infty}\int[\text{stuff}]\cdot g_m=\int\lim_{m\to\infty}[\text{stuff}]\cdot g_m$ must be justified. The simple approximation theorem does not give uniform convergence of the $g_m$'s, but even then uniform convergence is great for proper Riemann integrals... but for improper integrals it's not quite good enough - and you don't even have that! Similar comments for exchanging $\lim_n\int=\int\lim_n$; the fact we have a finite sum of $g_m$ doesn't help. $g$ is already a finite sum of one function, $g$ itself... and also, the number of terms in the finite sum is changing (a common difficulty) which makes limiting arguments harder to do correctly. Also, I notice you use a sneaky $\lim_n\lim_m=\lim_m\lim_n$ which again is not immediately justifiable (especially because the number of terms in the finite series is variable).
How would I do it? If we really want to avoid all Lebesgue formalisms whatsoever, let's say $f$ is bounded and continuous at $1$, and that both $f,g$ are Riemann integrable on all finite intervals with $|g|$ (note the absolute value) being improperly Riemann integrable in the sense $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-\infty,\infty)}\int_x^y|g|$ exists. I never actually need the stronger conditions of Riemann integrable $>$ measurable by the way, I'm just placing it in this context. All I need to know is that $|\int_{-\infty}^{-M}|g|+\int_M^\infty|g||<\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $M$. This is still true if $g$ is integrable in Lebegue's sense, by an easy monotone convergence argument.
So... let $\epsilon>0$. Find $M>0$ such that $|\int_{-\infty}^{-M}|g|+\int_M^\infty |g||<\frac{\epsilon}{4(1+\sup|f|)}$. Let $0<\delta<1$ be such that $|f(1+x)-f(1)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+\int_{\Bbb R}|g|)}$ for $|x|<\delta$. Let $N:=1+\lceil M\delta^{-2}\rceil\in\Bbb N$. Then, for all $n\ge N$: $$\begin{align}\left|\int_{-n}^nf(1+x/n^2)g(x)\,dx-f(1)\int_\Bbb Rg(x)\,dx\right|&\le\int_{-M}^M|f(1+x/n^2)-f(1)|\cdot|g(x)|\,dx+|f(1)|\cdot\int_{(-\infty,-M]\cup[M,\infty)}|g|\\&\quad\quad+\int_{-n}^{-M}|f(1+x/n^2)|\cdot|g(x)|\,dx+\int_M^n|f(1+x/n^2)|\cdot|g(x)|\,dx\\&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+2\sup|f|\cdot\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-M}|g|+\int_{M}^\infty|g|\right)\\&<\epsilon\end{align}$$
As desired.
What's the main point here? I fixed the interval $[-M,M]$, because there I can get sufficiently good convergence. Uniform convergence "on $(-n,n)$" doesn't really make sense and isn't really true.
